# catch ids with 'for' in js help pls

Tags: javascript

I want to catch 10 inputs with JS, and put all them in a array[10], but I dont know any method to do this yet, I tried searching and all i could find was this, but doesnt seem to work.

```js
var i = 0;
var menor, maior;
function fibonacci() {
 
}
function calcularMenor() {
 
}
function calcularMaior() {
    var n = new Array();
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var input = "input";
        var inputNumber = "" + i.toString();
        var inputId = input.concat(inputNumber);
        n[i] = document.getElementById(inputId).innerHTML;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = n[1];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Exercicio com Arrays</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div id="site">
   <div id="fibonacci">
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Sequência de Fibonacci:</legend>
     Limite Fibonacci: <input type="number" id="numFibonacci" min="1" value="1"><br>
     <button>Exibir elemento na posição</button>
    </fieldset>
   </div>
   <div id="vetor">
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Vetor</legend>
     <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input0">
     <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input1">
     <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input2">
     <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input3">
     <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input4">
     <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input5">
     <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input6">
     <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input7">
     <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input8">
     <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input9">
    </fieldset>
    <button name="exibir" onClick="()">Exibir MAIOR elemento</button>
    <button name="exibir" onClick+"()">Exibir MENOR elemento</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

At the moment I want to work only on the 'vetor' div, the fibonacci code i'll do it later

Comment: You may use jQuery. Take a look at the id-selector and the [val()-method](http://api.jquery.com/val/). First of all however you have to fix your html (there are + signs instead of = and other things) and probably provide some background details what you want to achieve with that array of items.

Comment: what exactly you want to do?What is the output you are looking for?

Comment: I have to use JS as my professor asked to. The output is picking the value of input id="input0" and putting into the array n[0], and doing the same process for the others inputs and arrays, but with for instead of catching manually.
Edit: i fixed the '+' symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hay paulo, you can get values and put that value into array like:

```
let dataArray = []
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    dataArray.push(document.getElementById(`input${i}`).value);
}
alert(dataArray);
document.getElementById('numFibonacci').value = dataArray
```

initialise an array and put values one-by-one in that array.

Here is your full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exercicio com Arrays</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div id="site">
            <div id="fibonacci">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Sequência de Fibonacci:</legend>
                    Limite Fibonacci: <input type="number" id="numFibonacci" min="1" value="1"><br>
                    <button>Exibir elemento na posição</button>
                </fieldset>
            </div>

            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Vetor</legend>
                    <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input0">
                    <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input1">
                    <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input2">
                    <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input3">
                    <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input4">
                    <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input5">
                    <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input6">
                    <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input7">
                    <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input8">
                    <input type="text" name="inputVetor" id="input9">
                </fieldset>
                <button name="exibir" onClick="putvalues()">Exibir MAIOR elemento</button>
                <button name="exibir" onClick+"()">Exibir MENOR elemento</button>
            </div>
            <div id="vetor"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function putvalues() {
            let dataArray = []
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                dataArray.push(document.getElementById(`input${i}`).value);
            }

            document.getElementById('vetor').innerHTML = dataArray
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand that, can you explain how to put all the values of name="inputVetor" in one array? Btw, i'm just focusing on everything inside the div id="vetor", i'll try fibonacci later

Comment: `document.getElementById('vector').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dataArray)`

Comment: I wish this will help you.